# Animate rigged character using 3d joint location coordinates

Tags: pose-mode

I have the (x,y,z) coordinates of ~20 joints of a person frame-by-frame.

Anyone know how I can use these coordinates to animate a 3d rigged model? Can I directly animate from the coordinates? Or will I have to use the x,y,z coordinates to calculate bone angles and use that? Some detailed guidance would be helpful, as I am pretty lost right now

Comment: You'll need additional information, even with 2 position (head and tail of a bone) it isn't given that they maintain the same distance. Furthermore even when pointing from pos1 to pos2, a bone could still *roll* around it's own (y) axis.

Comment: Hm true. I think for my application it's ok if I set a fixed y rotation for the bones.